# accept input from user and display array and multiplication (CLOSE)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

This is the code of accept input from user and display array and multiplication and put it in table form.

```
       <?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $n1 = $_POST['num1'];
            $n2 = $_POST['num2'];
        }
        else 
        {
            $n1 = 0;
            $n2 = 0;
        }


        function UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange($min, $max, $quantity) {
            $numbers = range($min, $max);
            shuffle($numbers);
            return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
        }



         $numberArray = array(
            UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(1,10,$n1),
            UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(1,10,$n2))
        ?>            
     <form action="" method="post">

         <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="value 1"><br>
         <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="value 2"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
     </form>    
          <?php

        printTable($numberArray); //panggilan function apa yg nk tunjuk
        function printTable($numberArray) {
            // Placeholder
            $result = [];

            // Setup the multiply
            foreach ($numberArray[1] as $key1 => $value1) {
                $tmp = array($value1); // add index y-axis
                foreach ($numberArray[0] as $key0 => $value0) {
                    $tmp[] = $value0 * $value1;
                }
                $result[] = $tmp;
            }

            // Add index the x-axis
            array_unshift($result, array_merge(array(" "), $numberArray[0]));

            // display the result into table form
            echo "<table border='1' align='center'>";
            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                echo "<tr>";
                foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                    if ($k == 0 || $key == 0) {
                        echo sprintf("<td><b>%s</b></td>", $v);
                        continue;
                    }
                    echo "<td>$v</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }

        ?>
```

1. Here can accept insert from user and auto generate number in array form which means user enter 5 in the textbox1 and 6 in the textbox2, it will generate number 3,4,5,2,1 and 2,3,4,1,2,3.
2. How I can capture this number put inside

   $numberArray = array(
                   array($display1),
                   array($display2)
               );

Comment: What do you mean with capture the number?

Comment: if user enter textbox1 = 5, textbox2 = 6 and click button populate, in another textboxarray1 and textboxarray2 will be generate number 3,4,5,2,1 and 2,3,4,1,2,3 (for example). how to capture number array already generate put into table and calculation like this photo: https://gyazo.com/ebef8fae733a2cd313b4044f719d27f6

Comment: @Epodax: Do u get I mean?

Comment: This is the actual code for display  https://gyazo.com/34f68eae72b0ab771d4ee9f9b124ea9a